# Flow Chart on a straight line in latex

Tags: tikz-arrows, workflow

How can I draw a flowchart that looks like this? [image]

I know how to draw block diagrams but I have never seen an example of a work flow diagram like this. Especially I am having a hard time on generating curly arrows. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Show us what you've done so we can add to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TikZ solution. To draw with `brace`, one needs `decorations.pathreplacing` from tikzlibrary. The syntax is displayed below where `amplitude` and `raise` can be changed to suit one's need. The two points are starting/ending points where braces with be drawn in between.

```
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=15pt},] 
(10,0)--node[below=0.5cm,mybox2]{Spectra Collection \\ (Measurement-based Sampling)}(7,0);
```

[image: output]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,,positioning}
\tikzset{mybox/.style = {rectangle, text width=4cm,minimum height=2cm,align=center},
mybox2/.style = {rectangle, text width=6cm,minimum height=2cm,align=center} 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (0,0)node[pos=0,below]{\tiny $t_k\,\si{\s}$} --
node[pos=0.1,above=-15pt,mybox] {Time \\Update}
node[pos=0.6,above=-15pt,mybox] {Blob \\Extraction}
node[pos=0.2,below]{\tiny $t_n\,\si{\s}$} 
node[pos=0.5,below]{\tiny $t_k+\SI{0.1}{\s}$}
node[pos=0.7,below]{\tiny $t_m\,\si{\s}$}
node[pos=1,below]{\tiny $t_n+\SI{0.4}{\s}$}
(10,0);
\draw[thick]  (0,-5pt)--(0,5pt) (2,-5pt)--(2,5pt)  (5,-5pt)--(5,5pt)  (7,-5pt)--(7,5pt)  (10,-5pt)--(10,5pt);
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=15pt}] 
(5,0)--node[below=0.5cm,mybox]{Panchromatic Image \\ Acquisition}(0,0);
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=30pt},] 
(2,0)--node[above=0.8cm,mybox2]{Spectra Collection \\ (Prediction-based Sampling)}(10,0);
\draw[decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=15pt},] 
(10,0)--node[below=0.5cm,mybox2]{Spectra Collection \\ (Measurement-based Sampling)}(7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably load [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and use `\si{\s}` for typesetting the seconds. (I assume that all the `s`s on the timeline are seconds and not variables.)

Comment: Advices accepted and code changed accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a tikz solution to this and yes you are right, those "s" represents seconds.

Comment: It should be `\si{\s}` and not `\si{s}`, even though the outputs are identical. Also, there should be a small space (`\,`) just before `\si{\s}` ... just to be pedantic.`:-)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg -- Sorry for the late response and thanks for the correction.

Comment: No problem. `:)` It's still not totally perfect, so I've taken my liberty and added the changed for the code with the units myself. (I hope it's okay; just roll it back if it isn't.) Also, the picture should be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I did this with stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\newcommand\vstrut[1][]{\makebox[0pt]{\rule[-1ex]{1pt}{2ex}}\mnote{#1}}
\def\mnote#1{\brlap{$\scriptstyle#1$}}
\def\dx#1{\hbox to #1 {}}
\def\dline#1{\hbox to #1 {\hrulefill}}
\def\dubrace#1{\hbox to #1 {\upbracefill}}
\def\ddbrace#1{\hbox to #1 {\downbracefill}}
 \begin{document}
\stackunder[-1ex]{%
  \Shortstack{Time\\Update\\ \dx{1in}}%
  \Shortstack{%
    Spectrum Collection\\(Prediction-based Sampling)\\ \ddbrace{3.5in}\\
    Blob\\Extraction\\ \dx{3.5in}}%
}{%
  \Shortunderstack{
    \vstrut[t_k\mathrm{s}]\dline{1in}\vstrut[t_n\mathrm{s}]\dline{1.25in}%
    \vstrut[t_k + 0.1\mathrm{s}]\\ \dubrace{2.25in}\\Panchromatic Image\\Aquisition}%
  \dline{1in}%
  \Shortunderstack{
    \vstrut[t_n\mathrm{s}]\dline{1.25in}\vstrut[t_k + 0.4\mathrm{s}]\\
    \dubrace{1.25in}\\Spectra Collection\\(Measurement-based Sampling)}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should probably load [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and use `\si{\s}` for typesetting the seconds. (I assume that all the `s`s on the timeline are seconds and not variables.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I had not "seen" it in those terms (seconds), but I think you are right.